# how to define a string of 20 bytes

Tags: assembly, x86, llvm, mach-o

I'm writing an assembly code that copies at most 20 bytes from a source to a destination. I've tried to define my two global vars like this:

```
.section __DATA,__data
  src:
        .string "Hello"
  dst:
        .string 20
```

but the second definition looks wrong:

```
cpystr.s:5:10: error: expected string in '.string' directive
        .string 20
```

how can I define an area of memory of 20 bytes then?

Comment: What assembler is this?

Comment: mac's llvm compiler, mach-o format

Comment: `.string` is for initializing data with a string. You seem to want `.space 20`